# What is the difference between tacking onto the PATH variable and creating a new one?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

I noticed that during some installation of Python, a new environment variable was created called PYTHONPATH.

In every tutorial I've ever watched, the method of setting up command line use has been to tack the directory of the .exe file onto the PATH environment variable using a semi-colon:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
C:\Program Files\Python38;
C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts;
%PyCharm Community Edition%;
C:\Users\WNeill\AppData\Roaming\npm;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin; 
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin
```

However, as I was troubleshooting some problems getting MySQL to launch from the command line, I noticed there is a separate PYTHONPATH variable. It references the directory of a 32 bit python version that no longer exists on my machine.

This leads me to the question, does the PATH variable do anything special, or can I have separate variables for each directory like `SQLPATH`, `PYTHONPATH`, `JAVAPATH` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PATH variable is special in that it is used by the command processor (cmd.exe) to find any executable files that are called but do not exist in the current directory. This retrieval is done automatically and performed in the order given in the PATH variable. For example calling any .exe file that resides in your Python38 folder or Java installation folder from anywhere on your file system, you could just type in the filename (like `javac myfile.java` for example) and hit enter to get it executed (assuming the Java installation directory is part of the PATH variable).
You can try to play with `where` on the command line to get a clue about which executable is really called, if you just type in a filename without explicit path. Type `where /?` on the command line to get the help description. For example `where java` should give you a path like `C:\Program Files\Java\Java 1.8\java.exe` or something.
The PATH functionality is the same reason why it is possible to just type `calc` into a command line and see the calculator app being invoked. It is because usually `C:\Windows\System32\` is part of the PATH and `calc.exe` is sitting in this directory.

If you define your own environment variables like PYTHONPATH etc. this "auto search" feature will not be invoked automatically on such definitions. However, you are able to use these definitions inside of your batch files to do stuff and also Python or whatever application creates those variables might use them to retrieve their files. If this variable would be missing and the application checks on this variable specifically to invoke or retrieve some files on this path then the application would fail even if the directory was added to the PATH environment variable (unless the application also tries to just invoke a file and hopes that it is resolved via the PATH automatically).

In your own batch file you could do something like

```
SET JAVAPATH=....
SET PYTHONPATH=....
SET PATH=%JAVAPATH%;%PYTHONPATH%
```

to build up your PATH variable in a more structured manner. Note that this definition of PATH is only valid in the scope of your batch file. It will not alter the PATH maintained by Windows in the System Settings.